# How to subtract two numbers and add the result to the third number in a sequence?

Tags: c#, listbox

I am trying to write a C# program that takes an input value from user and then puts that value inside a sequence, then prints the result of every calculated number of the sequence inside a listBox. the sequence is like this:

S = 1 - X + X^2 / 2! - X^3 / 3! + X^4 / 4! - ...

First number that will be shown inside the listBox every time the program starts is 1. i am stuck at the part where i should subtract 1 from the user input (X) and then add the result to the third calculated number of the sequence. For example if user enters 2 as input, first output is 1, second output is -1 and then the program should add the result (-1) to the third calculated number of the sequence which is 2 and output should be 1. again subtract the result (1) from the fourth calculated number and again add the result to the fifth calculated number of the sequence and ...

so far i wrote this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int x = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        listBox1.Items.Add("1".ToString());
        double numerator = 1, Fact = 1, firstNum = 1, result;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
        {
            numerator = x * numerator;
            Fact = Fact * i;
            result = numerator / Fact;
            firstNum = firstNum - result;
            listBox1.Items.Add(firstNum.ToString());
        }
```

But i can't figure out how to write the code for the parts of sequence that should add the result to the next calculated number. Above codes will only subtract the result from next number and prints the result, but now how to add the result of subtraction to the next number and prints it again to the listbox?

First number of sequence - Second number of sequence = Result (show in listbox)

Result + Third number of sequence = Result (show in listbox)

Result - Fourth number of sequence = Result (show in listbox)

Result + Fifth number of sequence = Result (show in listbox)

I am very sorry if i explained the problem bad, i tried to be as specific as possible. I know i'm missing a very tiny piece, but i can't figure out what is it, and sorry for the writing, english is not my native language.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide anitial number sequence and the result sequence you want to calculate?

Comment: If i understand correctly. for example user enters 2 in the textbox. First output is 1, second output is (1-2=-1), third output is (-1+4/2=1), fourth output is (1-8/6= -0.33), fifth output is (-0.33+16/24= 0.33), sixth output is (0.33-32/120= 0.064). This is the first sixth output of sequence, but i want it continue like this till number 20 or even let the user enter another number in a second textbox as sequence limit.

Comment: sorry, till number 20 i mean the 20th number of sequence. until " i " is equal to 20 in the loop. (i<=20)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost on the right track. Just missing few things.

**Here is the corrected version of your program --->**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int x = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
    listBox1.Items.Clear();
    listBox1.Items.Add("1".ToString());
    double numerator = 1, Fact = 1, firstNum = 1, result=0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
    {
        Fact = 1;       // Reinitialising every time for new denomerator.
        numerator = Math.Pow(x, i);     // This is how power is calculated.
        for (int j = 1; j<=i; j++)      // One more inner loop is needed for Factorial.
            Fact = Fact * j;
        result = numerator / Fact;
        firstNum = firstNum + (Math.Pow(-1, i) * result);   // This is the main logic for alternate plus minus.
        listBox1.Items.Add(firstNum.ToString());
    }
}
```

I hope it solves your problem. :)

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what i was missing, a second inner loop for Factorial and also i didn't know about the logic for alternate plus minus. Once again thank you so much for taking your time and helping me.

Comment: You are welcome.
You could have got the solution on your own, just learn how to debug the programs.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to store the result of the subtraction(firstNum - result) to a variable and then add it to the next number?

Comment: I tried this, but it will print some weird results and also the program will give more than 20 outputs.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the sequence formula is

> **f(i) = (-x)^i / i!** for i in 0..N, 0! = 1

which can be produced as follows

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int x = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
    listBox1.Items.Clear();
    double numerator = 1, denominator = 1;
    int i = 0;
    while(true)
    {
        var result = numerator / denominator;
        listBox1.Items.Add(result.ToString());;
        if (++i > 20) break;
        numerator *= -x;
        denominator *= i;
    }      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        var seqLimit = Convert.ToInt32(Textbox1.Text);
        var numberX = Convert.ToInt32(XTextBox.Text);
        ListBox1.Items.Clear();
        var result = 1.0;
        for (var i = 1; i <= seqLimit; i++)
        {
            ListBox1.Items.Add(result);
            if (i%2 == 0) result = result + (Math.Pow(numberX, i)/Factorial(i));
            else result = result - (Math.Pow(numberX, i)/Factorial(i));
        } 


    static int Factorial(int n)
    {
        if (n <= 1)
            return 1;
        int result = 1;
        for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
        {
            result = result * i;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Try this, it would work.